# Close, minimize and maximize buttons not appearing in some apps

Tags: release-loki, minimize

I have installed elementaryOS Loki and in some applications those buttons don't appear. They are still there, if I click where they are supposed to be I can close, minimize and maximize windows, but they are completely invisible in a lot of apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change theme, i install tweaks and that works for me.

install this if you wanna get tweaks.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

tweaks install on your system settings.

you can use themes for gtk and change theme.